# Understanding DRAM specs and choosing memory modules

Tags: laptop, memory

I have an HP Probook 450 G5 laptop. It uses a Hynix 8GB memory module with the description SK Hynix 8GB DDR4 1Rx8 PC4-2400T SA1-11 HMA81GS6AFR8N.

I would like to upgrade the memory to 16 GB. The corresponding 16 GB memory module seems to use the spec SE1-11 instead of SA1-11. Otherwise the specs are very similar (16GB DDR4 2Rx8 PC4-2400T SE1-11).

I would be most grateful if anyone could help me with the following questions:

1. What is the meaning of the SA1-11 versus the SE1-11?
2. Would this 16GB module be compatible with the HP Probook 450 G5?
3. Would I be able to use the 16 GB module alongside the 8 GB module?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Half duplicate of https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/15799/can-i-have-memory-ram-issues-if-i-have-one-slot-with-8gb-and-another-with-16gb?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, that is a helpful answer. Information on the meaning of SA1-11 and SE1-11 would also be helpful.

Comment: I don't think that is much of a difference, but I can't know for sure since I don't mix memory very often and when I do I just use the same capacity. Probably they are close enough for my linked answer to apply

Comment: @BruceButton It's my *personal* opinion that the "what is the meaning of SA1-11 vs SE1-11" portion of your question is off-topic here at HardwareRecs, as it seems to me that's more in the "tech support" arena.  That's just my personal perspective on it!

Comment: @JeffSchaller thanks for your comment. I must confess, although I try to post in the correct place I'm not completely familiar with all the technicalities of the different sections, so apologies if this is off-topic.

Comment: Stack Exchange is its own system, and can take a little bit to get used to! /help/on-topic on each site is a good starting point for learning what that site is about. There's also the /tour page as well as the rest of the Help Center. Welcome to SE!